# ¿Cómo soluciono el error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'?

Tags: asp.net

Estoy intentando ingresar un valor de tipo "DateTime" en un TextBox para agregar valores a un tabla y cuando le doy agregar me sale "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Acá el código:

```
var Depart = new Department();
//{
    Depart.Name = txtName.Text;
    Depart.GroupName = txtGroupName.Text;
    Depart.ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifiedDate.Text);
//};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu fecha en el campo de texto tiene que tener algun problema de formato.. queres mostrarnos como es?

Answer (score -1):

intenta  esto

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifiedDate.Text).ToString();
```

Comment: Recuerda siempre comentar tu código y explicarlo (yo no te voté negativo), pero es claro que tu aporte por su extensión es de baja calidad

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con:

```
Depart.ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtModifiedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Recuerda siempre comentar tu código y explicarlo, pero es claro que tu aporte por su extensión es de baja calidad